# Understanding git fetches and your local repo

Tags: git, git-branch, git-pull, git-checkout, git-fetch

I read that, after doing a `git fetch`, your local repo has all the commits from the original repo, but that they are "not yet integrated into the cloned repository's local branches".

**What does this mean/imply?**

Do I then need to checkout my branch to pull the changes down into my local working copy? Or does it imply something else? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Git has two commands to update itself from a remote repository. git
>   fetch will synchronize you with another repo, pulling down any data
>   that you do not have locally and giving you bookmarks to where each
>   branch on that remote was when you synchronized. These are called
>   "remote branches" and are identical to local branches except that Git
>   will not allow you to check them out - however, you can merge from
>   them, diff them to other branches, run history logs on them, etc. You
>   do all of that stuff locally after you synchronize.
>
> The second command that will fetch down new data from a remote server
>   is git pull. This command will basically run a git fetch immediately
>   followed by a git merge of the branch on that remote that is tracked
>   by whatever branch you are currently in. Running the fetch and merge
>   commands separately involves less magic and less problems, but if you
>   like the idea of pull, you can read about it in more detail in the
>   official docs.

[Copied from here](http://gitref.org/remotes/)

Comment: This answer covers the basics but is technically wrong: you *can* `git checkout` a remote branch like `origin/master`, you just get into the "detached HEAD" state when you do that.

Answer (score 1):

`git fetch` updates the local copies of remote-tracking branches.  If the remote you have configured is `origin` (which is usually the case) then `git fetch` will update `origin/master` as well as any other branches that exist remotely.  These branches point to the commit that the remote branches are currently on.

For example, consider this invocation of `git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --graph --decorate --all`:

```
* 46960d3 (origin/master) Commit 5
* 8b050c8 Commit 4
* cee210b (HEAD, master) Commit 3
* 075aafe Commit 2
* 69ade0a Commit 1
```

In this case, `git fetch` retrieved two new commits (4 and 5), but the local `master` branch is still behind.

To rectify the situation, one must check out `master` if it is not already checked out (`git checkout master`) and then merge with the new commits (`git merge origin/master`).

`git pull` is effectively a synonym for "fetch from the remote that the current branch is tracking, then merge with the tip commit that was fetched."  In this case it would be equivalent to `git fetch origin && git merge origin/master`.